# PHP If isset() Not Returning Value For HTML Input

Tags: php, forms, function, pdo

I'm having issues with a PHP form that is using the `isset()` function for input values that have been pulled from a database. When I use the below code, the isset function is returning nothing to the input fields on an edit client form. I'm in need of some help on how I can get this head scratching problem solved.

**edit-client.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/bootstrap.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/head.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/nav.php';

$client     = getClient(request()->get('client_id'));

$firstName  = $client['first_name'];
$lastName   = $client['last_name'];
$notes      = $client['notes'];
$buttonText = 'Update Client';
?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php include __DIR__ . '/inc/sidebar-nav.php'; ?>

            <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto mt-4 col-lg-10 px-4 main">
                <h1 class="h3 border-bottom pb-3 mb-4 text-primary">Edit Client</h1>

            <form method="post" action="/procedures/procedure-edit-client.php">

                <label for="first_name" class="text-muted">First Name</label>                    
                <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php if(isset($firstName)) echo $firstName; ?>">

                <label for="last_name" class="text-muted">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($lastName)) echo $lastName; ?>" required>

                <label for="notes" class="text-muted">Notes</label>
                <textarea id="notes" name="notes" class="form-control" rows="10"><?php if(isset($firstName)) echo $firstName; ?></textarea>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-action btn-primary">
                    <?php
                        if(isset($buttonText)) echo $buttonText;
                        else echo 'Add New Client';
                    ?>
                </button>
            </form>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>

<?php require_once __DIR__ . '/inc/footer.php';
```

**functions.php**

```
function getClient($clientId) {
    global $db;

    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id = ?";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $clientId);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: post a `var_dump($client)` please

Comment: `if(isset($firstName)) echo firstName;` is missing a `$`

Comment: Your error reporting must not be turned on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @sietse85 var_dump($client) returns bool(false)

Comment: well there you have it ;) debug your query

Comment: also check @apokryfos comments about firstName missing a $

Comment: post your code of function `getClient`

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos thanks for pointing that out, added the $ to firstName, but nothing happened :(

Comment: that is because `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is returning false

Comment: @sietse85 is this where the issue lies then? I'm just starting to get into PHP & DB and I'm still trying to get my head around it. Everything has been working great up until this point

Comment: yes getClient returns false, and not an array as you expect in your code.

Comment: can do a `var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());` just above the return statement in your getClient() function?

Comment: if you haven't enabled PDO error handling, then do with http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and see what it throws back, along with what's been said about error reporting.

Comment: btw, don't use `isset()` for inputs, use `!empty()`.

Comment: @sietse85 I have done a var_dump as requested and I get the output of: 
`array(1) { [0]=> array(10) { ["client_id"]=> string(1) "2" [0]=> string(1) "2" ["first_name"]=> string(9) "Angelique" [1]=> string(9) "Angelique" ["last_name"]=> string(6) "Cowley" [2]=>`

Comment: there you have you data now you will have to return the first row of the array ;)

Comment: *"is returning nothing to the input fields on an edit client form"* - what you posted is a SELECT, I don't see anything related to editing one's data. In either case, use PDO error handling.

Comment: `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(); return (!empty($result)) ? $result[0] : false;`

Comment: that should make your code work

Comment: Where would I need to put that line @sietse85?

Comment: see answer that i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i assume you only get one result so returning that first result:

```
function getClient($clientId) {
    global $db;

    try {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id = ?";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $clientId);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

        return (!empty($result)) ? $result[0] : false;

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

After that check you var_dump($client) again to see your data. Also when client is false, it could not find the client. Adjust your code to check for that also else $client is still empty.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not working as expected. I have tried a var_dump and I am still getting a array return of 0. I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: wat does var_dump($client) say after the change i suggested?

Comment: I get the output: bool(false)

Comment: that means no client was found with your query. Are you sure `request()->get('client_id')` is always giving a id? Try `var_dump(request()->get('client_id'));` to see if there is a clientId

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this sietse85, I managed to get the code up and running as expected :D